# Issues while setting up objectify with The Datastore

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application which uses objectify which i want to deploy in a Google Compute engine to access google datastore. I have been able to test this application in local development server using Objectify. I am also able to access the cloud datastore from the compute engine by following the documentation in https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/.

But when I deploy my application in the google compute engine I am not able to communicate with the google cloud datastore and am getting the following exception:
No API environment is registered for this thread.

I should be missing something. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Objectify currently only works with Datastore if you are running in Google App Engine (GAE), not for Datastore Access via Google Compute Engine (GCE).  There is an open issue https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/203

The reason it does not work on Google Compute Engine is apparently because the API for Datastore access in GCE is apparently different from the one used for GAE.